# Set Notification to a specific time

Tags: java, android, notifications, alarm

I want to set a notification to be shown in a specific time, like 10AM. I already searched this the web and did this, but I don't know what is wrong cause nothing is notifying! Here are my notification class:

```
public class notification extends AppCompatActivity {
    NotificationManager manager;
    Notification myNotication;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);
        manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(notification.this,about.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(notification.this, 1, intent, 0);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(notification.this);

        builder.setAutoCancel(false);
        builder.setTicker("this is ticker text");
        builder.setContentTitle("WhatsApp Notification");
        builder.setContentText("You have a new message");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.up);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setOngoing(true);
        builder.setNumber(100);
        myNotication = builder.getNotification();
        manager.notify(0, myNotication);
    }
```

And my main class(activity)(onCreate method):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        alarmMgr0 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(main.this,notification.class);
        intent.putExtra("uur", "1e");
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(main.this, 0, intent, 0);
        timeOff9 = Calendar.getInstance();
        timeOff9.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 01);
        timeOff9.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 46);
        timeOff9.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        alarmMgr0.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeOff9.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should modify this below code as your requirement

```
private void handleNotification() {
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 5000, pendingIntent);
}
```

and This is custom BroadcastReceiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Calendar now = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        int dayOfWeek = now.get(Calendar.DATE);
        if(dayOfWeek != 1 && dayOfWeek != 7) {
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = 
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.message_box_title))
                    .setContentText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.message_timesheet_not_up_to_date));
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        }

    }
}
```

And add manifest application tag:

```
<receiver
        android:name="be.menis.timesheet.service.AlarmReceiver"
        android:process=":remote" />
```

modify this code as your need i think this is useful

Comment: Thanks for answering , my API lvl is 14 , and how can I set it to a specific time?